# Get tweets that have a specific keyword and other optional keywords in python

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to filter real-time tweets from twitter, I have this list keywords=["Alex", "love","hate","hungry","happy"] I want to get tweets that has "Alex" and at least one keyword from given list. my code is below when I run it, it tracks the tweet that contains any words from the list. remember again I want "Alex" as the main tracking keyword, tweet should have "Alex" and at least one of those words "love","hate","hungry","happy".

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json

# consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
csecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
atoken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
asecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = all_data["text"]
        username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
        out = open('out1.txt', 'a')
        out.write(tweet.encode('utf-8'))
        out.write('\n')
        out.close()
        print username, " :: ", tweet
        return True

     def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
keywords = ["Alex", "love","hate","hungry","happy"]
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=keywords, languages=["en"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you store your tweet in a variable named `tweet`

```
keywords = ['love', 'hate', 'hungry', 'happy']
if "Alex" in tweet:
    if any(keyword in tweet for keyword in keywords):
        # get the tweet
```